# How to reduce the number of api calls to MongoDB by doing bulk read?

Tags: java, mongodb, aws-documentdb

I've an application where I've to fetch account information from the MongoDB by accountId . But the problem is each api call takes around 0.8 sec on average  so processing 70000 accounts would take around more than half a day. If I have all the accountIDs in my application already how can I reduce the round trips to database ?
I've already made the application multithreaded, its still not enough.

AccountId is the only identifying information. Any hack using AWS for DocuemntDB store would also work.

Comment: Are you looking for the [$in](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator?

Comment: @ray Yeah. Something like $in . But I don't think $in is the right choice for 70k params.

Comment: You can import your list into a collection and perform lookup to that collection like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/r5oT-VpdhIl)